# parameter in popBackStack (int id,int flags) function

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to remove the last two fragment of [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#FragmentTransaction()) from the stack on [Button](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button) [click event](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener).

for that, i go through the [android document](https://developer.android.com) for the function `popBackStack()` where i also got the `popBackStack()` with two different type of parameter i.e [`popBackStack (int id,int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack()) and [`popBackStack (String name,int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack())

according to [android document](https://developer.android.com) written for [`popBackStack (int id,int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack()) fuction is `It will Pop all back stack states up to the one with the given identifier.`

what should i pass at place of `id` in [`popBackStack (int id,int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack()) function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I did not try this code, but you can get the last two fragments using:

```
int index = getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1;
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry lastEntry = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(index);
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry secondLastEntry = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(index - 1);
```

And then you can use the `Id` of the `Fragment` to remove it from the `BackStack`.

```
popBackStack(lastEntry.Id, 0);
popBackStack(secondLastEntry.Id, 0);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry

Did you also try to just call `popBackStack()` twice without parameters?

Comment: Cool! Please mark it as answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Worked better than the solution with the tag.